# Return value 1 on FIRST INSTANCE of unique

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with Name and Area.
I want to run a query that returns that table with the addition of a 'Special_COUNT'
The count returns 1 on the firstmost Concat(Distinct(Name,Area); should return 0 otherwise
For example:

```
Name          |          Area          |     Special_COUNT      |      

ABCD          |          US            |          1             |
ABCD          |          US            |          0             |*Same Name/Region no value
ABCD          |          Asia          |          1             |*New Region
ABCDX         |          Asia          |          1             |*New Name
```

How can I get the above 'Special_COUNT' column into the results of my query?

Comment: I had time, so I worked up the query you need.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have any ranking functionality - you'll want to [read this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/) for setting up the variables for LEAD functionality in order to number the output correctly.

Use:

```
SELECT x.name,
       x.area,
       x.special_count
  FROM (SELECT t.name,
               t.area,
               CASE WHEN @name = t.name AND @area = t.area THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS special_count,
               @name := t.name, 
               @area := t.area
          FROM TABLE t, 
               (SELECT @area := NULL, @name := NULL) r) x
```

Tested on 4.1 - results match, thanks for supplying test data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction, after reading for a few hours and attempting to work this into my query, I'm stumped.  I cannot figure out how to put this in as a part of my bigger query...

Comment: If there isn't just one table as I listed above and the Name and Area's are pulled from two different tables, do you know where I would put the joins?  See my detailed question below...I'm confused on where to put the joins...

Comment: also what is the r?  Is that the ranking you speak of?

Comment: The `r` is a table alias - MySQL requires that you define a unique one for every subquery in a SELECT statement.  Ranking is the means of ranking 2+ records on arbitrary value(s).

Comment: Thank you-
so the r and the x are both names of derived tables?
what if name is in table t but area is in table s?  where would I put the join for t and s on if both tables where linked on lets say.
.linker

so inner join t on t.linker = s.linker

Comment: Yes - `x` and `r` are derived tables.  Some call them inline views, or subqueries.  Yes, if the columns are in different tables, you'll need to join the tables & correct the variable updates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

Your code looks so simple, alas I am not able to work this into a larger query (apologies for not providing an example query so that you could show me how this would work, below I have done that for you in the hopes that you can explain by example)

So given this original query below how would I revise it to  incorporate your data with the goal of obtaining a 'special_count' on allanimalnames.AnimalName per location.Area

I see the light at the end of the tunnel...

```
SELECT
CASE allanimalnames.animalID
    WHEN allanimalnames.animalID = 1 THEN "Dangerous!"
    WHEN allanimalnames.animalID <> 1 THEN "Cuddly"
END AS 'Animal Danger Levell,

allanimalsizes.SizeInFeet AS 'Length of the Animal',
allanimaltypes.AnimalTypeName AS 'Carnivor or Herbavore?',
location.Area AS 'Region this Animal is found in',
allanimalnames.AnimalName AS 'Name of this animal,
MAX(report.reportdate) AS 'Last Reported'
FROM
allanimalnames
INNER JOIN allanimaltypes ON allanimaltypes.atypeid = allanimalnames.atypeid
INNER JOIN allanimalsizes ON allanimalsizes.sizeid = allanimalnames.sizeid
INNER JOIN location ON location.locid = allanimalnames.locid
INNER JOIN report ON report.reportid = allanimalnames.reportid
WHERE
report.reportdate
BETWEEN '2008-01-01' AND '2009-01-01'
GROUP BY
allanimalsizes.SizeInFeet
allanimaltypes.AnimalTypeName
location.Area
allanimalnames.AnimalName
report.reportdate
```